# Stuck doing a common table expression to calculate total orders for each product category using NORTHWND

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, common-table-expression

Guys so as part of my job as a Data Support Analyst I am training up to become a software developer, my mentor gave me a group of test statements and this one seems way more advanced than anything I have done previously. The question is...

*

> 6)    Write a subquery or common table expression to calculate total
>   orders for each product category. that will Write a query that will
>   bring back each product name, the total number of orders made for the
>   product and join to the subquery or CTE to calculate the percentage
>   of sales that product represents of its product category. For example,
>   if Category of Soaps has 2 products; Blue Soup and Red Soap, blue soup
>   had 40 orders and red soaps had 10 orders I would expect to see the
>   following rows: Product Name   Total Orders       % of Category Red
>   Soap             40                           80%
>   Blue Soap            10                           20%

*

So far I have managed to get the following but I'm struggling to progress past this...

```
;WITH [Products] (CategoryId, TotalNumberOfOrders) 
AS  (

SELECT p.CategoryId, 
COUNT (OD.OrderID) as TotalNumberOfOrders
FROM [dbo].[Products] p  
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order Details] OD 
ON p.ProductID=OD.ProductID
GROUP BY p.CategoryId )

SELECT * From Products
```

Any help would be fantastic! ( I'm using NORTHWND database btw)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is

```
;WITH temp    AS  
(
   SELECT p.CategoryId, 
          COUNT (DISTINCT OD.OrderID) as TotalNumberOfOrders
   FROM [dbo].[Products] p  
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order Details] OD  ON p.ProductID=OD.ProductID
   GROUP BY p.CategoryId
)

SELECT p.ProductName, 
       Count(DISTINCT Od.OrderId) AS Total, 
       Count(DISTINCT Od.OrderId)*100/temp.TotalNumberOfOrders AS Percentage
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order Details] OD ON p.ProductId = OD.ProductId
INNER JOIN temp ON p.CategoryId = temp.CategoryId 
GROUP BY p.ProductId, p.ProductName, temp.TotalNumberOfOrders
```

Remember `Count(Distinct..)` to count `Order`.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sub-Query:

```
SELECT  P.ProductName, 
      COUNT(OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders,     
      CAST((CAST(COUNT(OrderID) AS DECIMAL(9,2)) / CAST(Derived_Table.CNT AS 
DECIMAL(9,2))) * 100 AS DECIMAL(9,2)) AS Percentage
  FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details]
        INNER JOIN  dbo.Products AS P
                ON  [Order Details].ProductID = P.ProductID  
        INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(F.OrderID) AS CNT, P.CategoryID
                            FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details] F
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Products P
                    ON F.ProductID = P.ProductID
                    GROUP BY P.CategoryID) AS Derived_Table
                ON P.CategoryID = Derived_Table.CategoryID                  
  GROUP BY [Order Details].ProductID,  P.ProductName, Derived_Table.CNT
 ORDER BY [Order Details].ProductID
```